# Add Product trough PrestaShop API with multistore

Tags: api, prestashop

I've coded some scripts to insert products, combinations, categories, images, etc over prestashop api. But now i need to activate multistore with one of them will not show prices.
I need to insert the products two times ? One for each store using the store specific api? Or is there any call that i can make to insert the product to all available stores?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug in PrestaShop. See http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCSX-6787

The method associateTo() is only available in a PrestaShop environment, and not when using the webservice and therefore is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the product call to

```
$product->associateTo($id_shops)
```

Where id_shops is an array with the shops ids where your product must be.

Comment: how can i do this with webservices. im using PS1.6.1.13.

Answer (score 0):

If the store are in the same group, you can add the *url parameter* `id_group_shop : id_group_shop=1`.
The images are still not linked to all the shops for me yet though.